# I want to call API in iphone ,I have a common url want to pass parametar according to my login page and registration page.we are using post method

Tags: objective-c

my url is below -
http://testing.safedatatech.com/ugifty/api/index.php

request for registration page -
REGISTER

response for registration post
 SUCCESS|FAILURE   
Error Code: 1.0 - Success 2.0 - Missing Field(s) 2.5 - Duplicate Email 3.0 - Invalid Request

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear, please edit for clarity.  Do you want to load the web page in a UIWebView?  or maybe programmatically call the url and get the result?  The latter would involve NSURLConnection with a post request setup in the NSHttpRequest.  Search the apple docs for those and read about it.